# Attempted access of inaccessible method for interface function?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I can't see what is wrong with this. I have a class MyConnectionManager that has this code:

```
public class MyConnectionManager {
    private var _delegate:NetworkConnectionDelegate;

    public function myfunc():void
    {
        this.delegate.onError(1);  // compile error here!
    }

    public function get delegate():NetworkConnectionDelegate
    {
        return _delegate;
    }

    etc

}
```

where NetworkConnectionDelegate is an interface and has a method onError()

```
public interface NetworkConnectionDelegate {
    function onError(x:int):void;
}
```

But the compiler (Flash Builder) says that onError is an inaccessible method when compiling MyConnectionManager. Why won't it compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

belive it or not, the above code is perfectly fine. It was a syntax error in a completely different source file that must have freaked out Flas Builer to cause the compiler error. Once i fixed the totally unrelated error, it compiled just fine. This sort of compile error would never have happened in a decent compiler like VV++ or XCode, but FB seems a liitle flakey. oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Interface describes public structure of class instance.
You need to create you class, and then implement it from defined interface.
Like,
Class:

```
public class NetworkConnectionDelegate implements IError {
...
    // implements to IError interface
    public function onError(x : int) : void {
    ..
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IError {
    function onError(x : int) : void;
}
```

Comment: I know I need to implement the interface, and I did in another class. This compile time error has nothing to do with whether or not the interface was implemented in another class.